Logic App Stateless workflow calls stateful workflow, but doesn't return message body
I'm trying to call Logic App stateful workflow from Stateless workflow, but it seems I don't receive the body message;
To demonstrate the issue - The parent logic app workflow invokes two child workflows (both are identical workflows, only difference is: one of them stateless and the other one is stateful), interestingly I don't receive output body from stateful workflow. Please refer the attached screenshots. Looking forward to get some suggestions to fix the issue.
Thanks,
Deepak Shaw.  



When you will invoke a stateful and stateless workflow from a stateless workflow then you will observe that the status code of both the invocations are 202 Accepted and 200 respectively. That's why it doesn't contain response body.
But If you will invoke a stateful and stateless workflow from a stateful workflow then both returns 200 status code. So, you can use the stateful workflow to invoke both types of workflows if you wish to see the response body.
I believe its an inbuild feature in the stateless workflow for stateful workflow.
I have used a stateful parent workflow to invoke stateful and stateless workflows and got response body in both the cases.




Thanks for the explanation. Does this mean I can't get the body from a child stateful workflow if the parent workflow is stateless? Is here any workaround ?

@DeepakShaw yes, you can't get the body if stateful workflow is invoked by stateless. As a workaround, you can invoke a stateful by a stateful workflow

This behaviour is in line with the documentation:



Parent workflow
Child workflow
Child behavior




Stateful
Stateful
Asynchronous polling pattern or synchronous ("fire and forget") with "operationOptions": "DisableAsyncPattern" setting


Stateful
Stateless
Trigger and wait


Stateless
Stateful
Synchronous pattern ("fire and forget")


Stateless
Stateless
Trigger and wait



If you want your stateless workflow to wait and receive a response from the stateful workflow then instead of using the Invoke a workflow action you should use the HTTP action to send a request to the HTTP URL from your stateful workflow:

Then the HTTP response will contain a body.

Thanks for the explanation. Does this mean I can't get the body from a child stateful workflow if the parent workflow is stateless? Is there any workaround?

@DeepakShaw I have added a solution to my answer.

Hi, That is a good idea but it is unsecured for production. It is good to create a PoC solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

@DeepakShaw Could you clarify why the parent workflow has to be stateless and the child workflow has to be stateful?
